# Can't install python3-pip

Tags: python3

I'm trying to install python3-pip but when I do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

I get I have dependencies problems with python3-dev, then I do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

and this goes on and on until I get to a dependency which the system claims to be already installed (`libpython3.5`)

So how can I solve this and properly install pip3?

This is the full output when I do try to install `python3-pip`:

```
    Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 python3-pip : Depende: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2) pero 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.2 va a ser instalado
               Recomienda: python3-dev (>= 3.2) pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

And this is the one I get with `python3-dev`

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 python3-dev : Depende: libpython3-dev (= 3.5.1-3) pero no va a instalarse
               Depende: python3.5-dev (>= 3.5.1-2~) pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

The rest of outputs for the rest of dependencies are just the same.

I don't know if the problem is in the last line "`E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.` which means `"The problems couldn't be solved, you've held broken packages"`.

Ubuntu version is 16.04.01LTS

Help please :/

Comment: Ubuntu version? :) Can you also try `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo apt install python3-pip -f`?

Comment: version is 16.04.01LTS, the same happens if I use those commands

Comment: sorry, might be `sudo apt-get -f install`, also try `dpkg-reconfigure --all`

Comment: yet another command: `sudo aptitude -f install` Also you're fully up-to-date with `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade` right?

Comment: you could also try `sudo apt-get purge python3 ; sudo apt install python3-pip`. Are you using PPAs? Disable them and downgrade your packages to the repository versions using `sudo ppa-purge repository_name` for each repository, then try installing python3-pip again (using PPAs is always risky because they mess with dependencies). It may be that you'll have to reinstall Ubuntu (backup first!) because you've messed something up somewhere, this is why Snappy is so good - it avoids this problem of dependency hell entirely.

Comment: wouldn't that remove my current python3? I don't wanna mess it up

Comment: Well if nothing else works as far as I know you don't have much choice I'm afraid. As it says, somehow you've ended up with broken packages.

Comment: using aptitude worked thank you very much =) why don't you write an answer with that solution so i give you rep and mark as solution?

Comment: Done :) Glad it worked for you, there's a lot of commands which can try to deal with dependency hell so I just suggested all the ones I've heard of, glad one worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command `sudo aptitude -f install`